# syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Tags: linux, bash

How can i determine what exactly the problem with my bash?
from time to time i run the script and get the following error:

```
download.sh: line 254: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
download.sh: line 254: `}'
```

but there's no '}' on line 254

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier to say something relevant if you'd include that script in your question

Comment: see if you can balance your braces. you'll find it.

Comment: as @popnoodles pointed out , the error is not indicative of the exact issue. A missed quote , braces . anything can be an issue. Set -x is best option

Comment: There may not be a `}` on line 254, but perhaps there is a variable on that line that occasionally contains a `}` in its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put set -x on the second line of your bash and run it again.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

......
......
......
```

Comment: You can also do `#!/bin/bash -x`